# Load Google Maps script only on certain pages in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a Rails application that consists of about 20 pages and only on two of those I'm using Google Maps.

Is there any better way to exclusively load the Google Maps API-script on certain pages than this (in the head tag):

`<%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" if params[:controller] == "shops" && params[:action] == "index" %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the head of you layout file use the following code

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

And then in the view file for the pages you want to include the javascript do this;

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" %>
<% end %>
```

You can put this content_for block anywhere in your view file and it will render in the head of the doc where you have defined the `yield :head`

More info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield and here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method

Comment: It is always better to put all javascripts at the footer of the page. Though it is not compulsory but recommended.

Comment: Good advice. The `yield :head` in this example can just as easily be used at the bottom of the doc in the layout file, and you can also rename `:head` if you like.