# Enable a js function only in certain actions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

By [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403591/load-google-maps-script-only-on-certain-pages-in-rails-app) I learned  a clever technique to include an external script only on certain pages.

But I know encounter a follow-up problem: the function (included in the `//= require_tree .`) that references that script is causing errors on all other pages (where the external script isn't included).

**Where in Rails do I put a function (or how do I write it), whose referenced external script only is included in those pages (actions) where it will be used, so that it doesn't create errors on all other pages?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to check in the view for the controller and action.
Add the controller and action as a class to your body tag.
Then in your javascript code, use an if conditional to check for those attributes and run the script.

Comment: Yes, that works: 
`if ($('body.posts.show').length >= 1) { function myFunction() } `
But it's funny how the web console still shows the same error message, but it only flashes it, just for a split second. Why does it take notice of the function at all, when the condition to run it fails?

Comment: just use if ($('body.posts.show').length {}). Something is off with the >= to me

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to the question as well for quite some time.

At the end, I realized:

1. I like the asset pipeline, and I don't want to deal with handling the assets myself. So I try as much as I can to have all my js files be handled with the asset pipeline
2. using content_for is very handy to included pieces of js where needed only on specific views:

on the layout file (layouts/application.html.erb) do

```
  <%= yield :scripts %>
```

inside the `<head>` tag

then on your specific view write

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script>
you js code goes here regularly 
</script>
<% end %>
```

then rails will know to take that bit and place it in :scripts
This will make sure your js bits are loaded only when you really need them

**If its specific files you want:**

place those files in a folder under assets/javascripts. Lets call it `Others`

in `Others` place `yourjs.js` files and in `application.js` manifest don't include that tree

now, sprockets will not take the files in `Others`.

Then you can use the method above with `content_for` to include specific files

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "Others/yourjs.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

there is `gem` [**Paloma**](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) dealing with page specific `javascripts` in Rails.

**Quick example:**

> ```
> The javascript callback file /assets/javascripts/paloma/users/new.js:
>
> Paloma.callbacks['users']['new'] = function(params){
>     // This will only run after executing users/new action
>     alert('Hello New Sexy User');
> };
>
> The Rails controller app/controllers/users_controller.rb:
>
> def UsersController < ApplicationController
>     def new
>         @user = User.new
>         # No special function to call, the javascript callback will be executed automatically
>         # just for this specific action.
>     end
> end
> ```

Comment: Interesting, in a project with more functions I can see this being really useful.

Comment: ok then please consider upvote my answer,if it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant (or efficient) way, but for this situation I check the controller and action before I add the `javascript_include_tag` in my layout.  Example:

```
<% if :controller == 'maps' && :action == 'show' %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, that's for the external script. But the question is how to best handle the function that is calling that script, because if I just put it among all other functions in the asset pipeline tree, it will try and call that script on all pages and causing errors when it doesn't find it...